# sql statement not working in jsp

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

This is the Code i have , I think its the Sql string that is not working correctly. im able to view the table and cick on the edit field but im only able to update the first row. i want to be able to select a row and than edit it according to its id .

```
//Database View
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Inventory</title>
</head>
<body>

    <%
    Connection connect = null;
    Statement s = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        connect =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/client", "rootroot", "rootroot");

        s = connect.createStatement();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM  client ORDER BY id ASC";

        ResultSet rec = s.executeQuery(sql);
        %>
        <table width="600" border="1">
          <tr>
            <th width="91"> <div align="center">id </div></th>
            <th width="198"> <div align="center">Email </div></th>
            <th width="97"> <div align="center">CountryCode </div></th>
            <th width="59"> <div align="center">Budget </div></th>
            <th width="71"> <div align="center">Edit </div></th>
          </tr> 
            <%while((rec!=null) && (rec.next())) { %>
                  <tr>
                    <td><div align="center"><%=rec.getString("id")%></div></td>
                    <td><%=rec.getString("first_name")%></td>
                    <td><%=rec.getString("last_name")%></td>
                    <td><div align="center"><%=rec.getString("blood_type")%></div></td>
                    <td align="right"><%=rec.getString("gender")%></td>

                    <td align="center"> <a href="editpage.jsp?id=<%=rec.getString("id")%>">Edit</a></td>
                  </tr>
            <%}%>
        </table>      
        <%  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if(s!=null){
                s.close();
                connect.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    %>
</body>
</html>

//Edit Page 
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>ThaiCreate.Com JSP Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>

    <%  
    Connection connect = null;
    Statement s = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        connect =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/client", "rootroot", "rootroot");

        s = connect.createStatement();

        String sql ="SELECT * FROM client";

        ResultSet rec = s.executeQuery(sql);
        if(rec != null) {
            rec.next();
        %>
    <form name="frmUpdate" method="post" action="SaveEdit.jsp?id=<%=rec.getString("id")%>"> 
        Update Form
            <table width="428" border="1">  
            <tr>
                <th width="181">
                <div align="left">Product ID </div></th>
                <td width="231"><%=rec.getString("id")%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="181">
                <div align="left">Name </div></th>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtName" size="20" value="<%=rec.getString("first_name")%>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="181">
                <div align="left">Email </div></th>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtEmail" size="20" value="<%=rec.getString("last_name")%>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="181">
                <div align="left">CountryCode </div></th>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtCountryCode" size="2" value="<%=rec.getString("blood_type")%>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="181">
                <div align="left">Budget </div></th>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtBudget" size="5" value="<%=rec.getString("gender")%>"></td>
            </tr>

            </table> 
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
        </form> 

        <% }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if(s!=null){
                s.close();
                connect.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    %>
</body>
</html>

// save page 
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>

    <%  
    Connection connect = null;
    Statement s = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        connect =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/client", "rootroot", "rootroot");

        s = connect.createStatement();

        String strCustomerID = request.getParameter("id");
        String strName = request.getParameter("txtName");
        String strEmail = request.getParameter("txtEmail");
        String strCountryCode = request.getParameter("txtCountryCode");
        String strBudget = request.getParameter("txtBudget");



        String sql = "UPDATE client " +
                "SET first_name = '"+ strName + "' " +
                ", last_name = '"+ strEmail + "' " +
                ", blood_type = '"+ strCountryCode + "' " +
                ", gender = '"+ strBudget + "' " +

                " WHERE id = '" + strCustomerID + "' ";
         s.execute(sql);

         out.println("Record Update Successfully");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if(s!=null){
                s.close();
                connect.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Please** do not write code like this. Use MVC, or at least move the query into a DAO ***and* please** don't use scriptlets.

Comment: Elliot what do you think is wrong with the Sql statement ?

Comment: @MuneebKhan: you should never put SQL or Java code directly into a JSP. A JSP is for the presentation of the data, not for data retrieval or processing

Answer (score 0):

please try s.executeUpdate(sql); instead of s.execute(sql);

Comment: Thanks for replying,  I have tried that but its not making any difference. I think the SQL statement is incorrect in the save page ,String sql ="SELECT * FROM client";

Comment: why do you think sql error in save page? which error show in your test? could you please show me your error?

Comment: earlier i had this : String sql = "SELECT * FROM  customer WHERE CustomerID = '" + id + "'  ";  and that wasn't working so i changed it too : String sql ="SELECT * FROM client"; then it started but im  obly able to update the first row.

Comment: Firstly you should write and test sql query only in your query browser. So you can know clearly it is sql error or not.

Answer (score 0):

First of all +1 for what Elliott Frisch says. Such spaghetti code is very bad practice.

Anyway, if I understand correctly your use case, then you need to obtain at the Edit page the `id` parameter from URL/request and add into the select appropriate condition so it looks something like

```
"SELECT * FROM client WHERE id = '" + clientId + "' "
```

If you don't put the condition in there, it will always return whole table and based on your code you're just taking the first row and ignoring the rest. Which is very inefficient way to work with DB.

Another thing you should consider are binds and something what is called `preparedStatement` - try to google it and learn something about it. The main reason to use it is to avoid SQL injection using which somebody can easily mess up or compromise your database data.

I personally would also replace * by listing of all columns which you really need.

Comment: Error : org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /editpage.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Pid
  location: class org.apache.jsp.editpage_jsp

Comment: You must have somewhere typo. The error says: `cannot find symbol symbol: variable Pid location` at the editpage.jsp line 13